# How to open from my app a specific activity from an other app?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, geo, google-street-view

I'm developing an app that opens other apps with intents and it works perfectly, but now i need to open a specific activity (or part of the app) and i don't know if it's even possible.

In this case i want to open Street View from the Google Cardboard app. I can't figure out or find the way of doing it.

Here is the intent im using (that works but does not full fill the task):

```
public void actionOpenCardboard(View view) {
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.samples.apps.cardboarddemo");
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can launch the `Activity` this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyExampleActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Also, you may need to add `android:exported="true"` to the `Activity`'s manifest from which you are invoking the above code.

Comment: He needs to open StreetView of Google Cardboard app from his app.

Comment: If that is an `Activity` inside the Cardboard app, he can use this, provided he knows the Activity name and package name of app

Answer (score 0):

You must find out how "Google Cardboard app" opens the "Street View" and what parameters are neccessarey (i.e. current lat, lon, zoom level).

If you are lucky the [IntentIntercept app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept&hl=en) can help you to find out the intent-details neccessary.

If you just need a map and it is not important if the map comes from "Google Cardboard app" or any other map app you can try ACTION_VIEW with a geo uri.

```
private void onButtonClick[] {
    double lat = 52.1;
    double lon = 9.2;
    double zoom = 10;

    // no need for  de.k3b.geo-lib for simple request:
    String uriGeoSimple = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, 
                "geo:0,0?q=%f,%f&z=%f", lat, lon,zoom);

    // (1) GEOClientActivity creates and sends an android ACTION_VIEW intent 
    // with coordinate
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriGeoSimple));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

For more details see

- overview https://github.com/k3b/k3b-geoHelper/wiki/Android-Geo-howto
- more about the geo-uri format: https://github.com/k3b/k3b-geoHelper/wiki/data#geo
- the docs come from open source k3b-geoHelper lib. you can easily do it without the lib as long as you donot want to parse and understand geo-uris

if you have found out the intent-details needed for "Google Cardboard app" please feel free to add the infos to https://github.com/k3b/k3b-geoHelper/wiki/Android-Geo-aware-apps